# $\alpha(b) - \alpha(a) \geq \int_a^b \alpha'(x) dx$ for $\alpha$ monotone and differentiable a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

This is a problem from Reed and Simon's book on functional analysis, where you are asked to prove $\alpha(b) - \alpha(a) \geq \int_a^b \alpha'(x) dx$ for a monotone function $\alpha$ that is differentiable a.e.. Based on the comments, I assume the answer if equality always holds is no, and that is when $\alpha$ is not differentiable everywhere.

This seems to be a direct application of the fundamental theorem of calculus, and so the proof is almost trivial and equality would hold everywhere. But this does not require the monotone assumption and seems too simple. Am I missing something?

Comment: Note: A monotone a.e. function could fail to be differentiable at some points.  Look at the hypotheses for the fundamental theorem of calculus before claiming this is an application of it.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you, it was careless of me to overlook the a.e. assumption.

Comment: Even a function that is strictly increasing everywhere could fail to be differentiable at some points.  So the key is not the "a.e. assumption."

Comment: @GEdgar Would the key property be montonicity, because that would show that $\alpha$ is integrable? I am a little stumped here.

Comment: The inequality is quite standard and it is proved using Fatou's Lemma.

Comment: @geetha290krm I was able to find that proof, I would have never thought to extend the domain beyond $b$. Is this a common trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly sure of the formulation you mean, but the basic result here is that if $\alpha$ monotonic on $[a,b]$ then $\alpha$ is differentiable ae and $\int_a^b\alpha(x)dx \le \alpha(b)-\alpha(a)$ with the famous Cantor function a typical example when $\alpha'=0$ ae so the integral is zero but $\alpha(1)=1, \alpha(0)=0$ so RHS is $1$

(if $x$ is in the Cantor set so it has a decimal representation $x=0.x_1..x_n.., x_k =0,2$, then $\alpha(x)=0.y_1..y_n..$ where $y_k=x_k/2$, while if $x$ is in an excluded interval, first, it's easy to show that at the two ends which are in the Cantor set, $\alpha$ defined above takes the same value and then $\alpha(x)$ is defined as the common value at the two ends)

The differentiability ae of $\alpha$ monotonic is a difficult result but the integral inequality follows easily from Fatou's lemma.

We assume wlog that $\alpha$ is non decreasing and we extend it to the right of $[a,b]$ a little as the constant $\alpha(b)$ respectively; then since for each $h>0$ small $\frac{\alpha(x+h)-\alpha(x)}{h} \ge 0$ while the limit as $h \to 0$ is $\alpha'(x)$ almost everywhere (namely at the points of differentiability of $\alpha$), Fatou's lemma says that $$\liminf_{h \to 0^+}\int_a^b\frac{\alpha(x+h)-\alpha(x)}{h}dx \ge \int_a^b\alpha'(x)$$

But now for small enough $h>0$, $$\int_a^b\frac{\alpha(x+h)-\alpha(x)}{h}dx=\frac{\int_{a+h}^{b+h}\alpha(x)dx-\int_a^b \alpha(x)dx}{h}=$$ $$=\alpha(b)-\frac{1}{h}\int_a^{a+h}\alpha(x)dx$$

Since $\alpha$ is nondecreasing $\frac{1}{h}\int_a^{a+h}\alpha(x)dx \ge \frac{1}{h}\int_a^{a+h}\alpha(a)dx=\alpha(a)$,

so $\alpha(b)-\alpha(a) \ge \alpha(b)-\frac{1}{h}\int_a^{a+h}\alpha(x)dx$ and letting $h \to 0$ we are done!

Edit later: just to make the above clear, it may happen that $\alpha$ is **monotone and continuous and the inequality is still strict** as in the Cantor function case; we have equality (a non trivial result though) if $\alpha'$ exists everywhere (though it may not be continuous) and is integrable (which here holds automatically since by monotonicity $\alpha'$ has constant sign where it exists and by Fatou, its integral is finite on any finite interval) which then implies $\alpha$ absolutely continuous, and of course if $\alpha$ is absolutely continuous regardless of monotonicity (when $\alpha'$ may exist only ae)

Comment: How do we know that the limit as $h \rightarrow 0$ is $\alpha'$ if we only have differentiability a.e.?

Comment: the limit is $\alpha'$ only ae (at the points of differentiability) but Fatou lemma applies for $f_n \ge 0, f_n \to f$ ae - I noted that but it may be not clear so I will edit to make it clear

Comment: So in the integral you obtained after applying Fatou's lemma, are you implicitly separating the domain of the integral on the right hand side into points where $\alpha$ is and is not differentiable (since the latter has measure 0)?

Comment: the integral of $\alpha'$ doesn't depend on a zero measure set so it's enough to know that $\alpha'$ exists a.e. (and is integrable since it is clearly non negative a.e.)

Comment: Got it, thank you for all your help and patience.

Comment: happy to help - again the inequality may be strict even if $\alpha$ is continuous; for equality we need either absolute continuity of $\alpha$ or the existence everywhere and integrability of $\alpha'$ (in the monotonic case, integrability follows)

Comment: What justifies the extension here? Why can we assume without loss of generality the extension case suffices?

Comment: @Mathematics - not sure what is the question; we have a function $\alpha$ monotonic on some interval $[a,b]$ and we need to prove the inequality above on $[a,b]$ so we can do whatever we want outside of $[a,b]$ if needed and here it is convenient to extend it a little to the right so we take $\alpha(x+h)$ uniformly; if you prefer we can fix $\epsilon >0$ and show by the same method that $\alpha((b-\epsilon)^+)-\alpha (a) \ge \int_a^{b-\epsilon}\alpha'(x)dx$ and let $\epsilon \to 0$ since $\alpha(b)\ge \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\alpha((b-\epsilon)^+)$

Comment: @Conrad I see. This must be obvious, but could you also clarify why the last line of the proof gives the desired result?

Comment: $\alpha(b)-\frac{1}{h}\int_a^{a+h}\alpha(x)dx=\int_a^b\frac{\alpha(x+h)-\alpha(x)}{h}dx$ so if we let take $\liminf_{h \to 0}$ we get $\alpha(b)-\alpha(a) \ge \liminf(\alpha(b)-\frac{1}{h}\int_a^{a+h}\alpha(x)dx)=\liminf(\int_a^b\frac{\alpha(x+h)-\alpha(x)}{h}dx) \ge \int_a^b\alpha'(x)dx$

Comment: @Conrad That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @Conrad  If $\alpha$ is increasing and $\alpha'$ exists everywhere, the conclusion that $\alpha$ is absolutely continuous and one has equality requires a deeper justification, I believe. In Leoni's _A First Course in Sobolev Spaces_ (1st ed), it follows from the Lusin (N) property (Theorem 3.39).  Or one can use the fundamental theorem of calculus for the Henstock-Kurzweil integral.  If you know a simpler argument I'd be glad to see one.

Comment: @Bob I completely agree and I think I mentioned it here that it is a non trivial theorem - maybe in the comment to the deleted answer but let me edit to make it clear